# Fans running all the time (never idle) in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, overheating, fan, fancontrol

I'm on an Acer Aspire-5750G and I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 from Ubuntu's website. It seems that whenever I turn on the computer, the fans *always run* - there's never an idle quiet time even when doing absolutely nothing! Now, I don't know whether this is a linux problem (I did not use this laptop for a while, I can't remember if it had problems under Windows, which I just erased).

Could it be a linux problem though? Do you know of what solutions out there exist for fan management/make the computer run more quietly? Perhaps Ubutnu is somehow throttling the CPU for no reason?

Comment: A good first start for fan/ heat problems is to look at what is going on using [psensor](http://www.tecmint.com/psensor-monitors-hardware-temperature-in-linux/). Also: [potentially related](http://askubuntu.com/questions/783551/how-do-i-tell-if-my-laptop-fans-can-be-controlled-by-ubuntu)

Comment: I installed Linux Mint Xfce instead, works much better. I can almost hear myself breathing when no tasks are running.